# " ? " in Kotlin Variable.. what's the purpose on this?

Tags: android, kotlin, syntax

I'm on learning basics of Kotlin language for Android Development :), i'm looking on some Kotlin syntax examples and i found out this example below.. **the thing that i don't know what is purpose with the `?` code..** i'm trying to find on Google but i can't understand completely what they explain, maybe you can help me with your explanation / your example on this one ? I'll appreciate that :)

Example :

```
fun main() {

    val myName :String? = "Maura"
    println("Your name is $myName")

    val myAge :Int? = 18
    println("Your age is $myAge")

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its null safety. Basically `Int?` represents nullable Int, while `Int` on its own is non-null.

```kotlin
var a: Int = 5
a = null  // error

var b: Int? = 5
a = null  // :)
```

In case you have `null` in your code, you cannot use them directly, if you want to for example call any function in them you have to follow null-safety: Use `?.` safecall operator, or `!!.` null assertion operator (usually shouldn't use).

```kotlin
val c = a.plus(4)  // :)
val d = b.plus(4)  // Hold on, I'm null you can't use "." on me :P

val e = b?.plus(4)  // Ok, if b is not null, add 4 and store that to e, otherwise store null to e
val f = b!!.plus(4)  // Hmm, if b was not null I'll add 4 to it and store to f, otherwise I'll crash your program throwing NPE
```

In contrast to this the type of `e` would be `Int?` as you've already read the thing. But what if you want to assign it a default value, easy use the elvis operator (`?:`):

```kotlin
val g = b?.plus(4) ?: 4  // if b is not null add 4 to it and store otherwise store 4 :)
```

**Edit:** The code in your sample works because there's String template calls `.toString()` and it is defined as `fun Any?.toString()` i.e. defined on a nullable receiver. So `b.toString` is valid though can be confusing.

```kotlin
println("Your age is $myAge")

// is same as
println("Your age is" + myAge.toString())

// toString is an extension function valid for nullable types, though member functions aren't :)
```

Answer (score 1):

well, this is [null safety feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) of Kotlin lang (awesome btw.)

in short: `?` next to type of variable/value means that this variable/value may be `null`. don't use it so often, it kind-of protects you from `NullPointerException`s, pretty often bug-cause in Java. also in your simple case it is unnecessary

```
var myName :String? = null // this is possible
var mySecondName :String = null // this isn't possible, build error

var myThirdName :String = "never null"
myThirdName = null // build error, this variable can't be null

myName = myName.replace("a", "b")
// build error above, trying to access nullable variable straightly
myName = myName?.replace("a", "b")
// null safety with ?, if myName is null it won't be executed and myName stay null

myThirdName = myThirdName.replace("a", "b") // this is possible
myThirdName = myThirdName?.replace("a", "b")
// this is also possible, but you will get a warning that ? is unnecessary
```